# How to increase 'framerate' or text print speed? (Text-based-adventure game)

Tags: python, performance, frame-rate

Trying to create a text-based adventure that involves interacting with a computer. So I found a way to get text to appear as though it's being typed onto the screen but it was too slow initially, so I bumped up the speed but now it's lagging a bit and several characters are appearing at a time instead of one at a time like on a computer.

I tried adding in the `fps = 60, time_delta = 1./fps` and upping the `fps` but it didn't do anything.

```py
import time
fps = 60
time_delta = 1./fps

def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep (0.05)
```

[image]

Comment: I take it that the delay_print function is responsible for printing the characters. If yes, you want to increase the sleep time interval to delay the characters from showing much longer

Comment: create minimal working code with your code so we could run it and see problem. I don't see `time_delta` or `fps` in your code.

Comment: FYI, you might checkout Pygame so you don't have to bother with this kind of thing...

Comment: from time import sleep

import time
fps = 240
time_delta = 8./fps

import sys

import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox

def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep (time_delta)

delay_print ("     Chapter 1    \n")
delay_print ("    ===========   \n")

sleep (3)

delay_print ('You wake up lying on your back, surrounded by fog.\n')

sleep (1)

Answer (score 0):

You tried to change the values of `fps` and `time_delta`, but you didn't use them in your command

```
time.sleep (0.05)
```

You probably wanted

```
time.sleep(time_delta)
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so quickly Marian. I've switched over time.sleep(0.05) to time.sleep(time_delta) and fiddled with the values but no change. I can change the speed at which stuff is coming out but the faster it goes, the more letters it bangs out at once if that makes sense?